# Keep Navigation rail appears in all app screens

Tags: flutter, navigation

I working on dashboard on ipad device,
I created the side navigation bar (NavigationRail),
the problem that when I push to another screen inside any navigation rail item the NavigationRail disappear,
so is there any way to keep navigation rail in screen even after navigate to another screens inside the same navigation rail item?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep `NavigationRail` after push, use nested navigator:

```dart
Scaffold(
  body: Row(
    children: [
      NavigationRail(
        // ...
      ),
      VerticalDivider(),
      Expanded(
        child: ClipRect(
          child: Navigator(
            onGenerateRoute: (settings) => MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => Parent(),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
)
```

Then pushing from `Parent` will replace screen part only inside the `Navigator`.

Comment: thanks for your comment bro, but in above solution the NavigationRail looks like recreated when push to another screen 
I want to ask you if there is any way to do it like TabBarController behavior in IOS